# How do I clear the read-only flag from a file in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, readonly

I need to clear the read-only flag of a file in my Perl program that runs on Windows.

I know `system("attrib -r $filename")` would work, but I was wondering if there is no built-in option in Perl to do it. `chmod 777, $filename` doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,

splintor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `chmod 0777, $filename`. You need the permissions in octal notation.

Answer (score 5):

The most common way to handle this sort of thing is indeed with `chmod`.  I was able to remove the read-only flag using the following with success:

```
chmod 0777, $filename;
```

This is using `chmod`'s [octal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_numbers).

I'm using [Strawberry Perl 5.8.8](http://www.strawberryperl.com) on Windows Vista 64 bit.

Comment: The difference is that you added a zero - 0777, and I used 777, which didn't work.